# Event pattern in AWS EventBridge filter using fields, not content

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

I know we can have AND condition in event pattern, for example:

```
{
  "field1": ["option1", "option2"],
  "field2": ["option3"]
}
```

is there anyway, we can add a OR condition between `field1` & `field2`? So the event rule will be satisfied on both cases:

- `{ "field1": "option1" }`
- `{ "field1": "option2" }`
- `{ "field2": "option3" }`
- `{ "field1": "option1", field2: "option3" }`

please note that setting up multiple rule is not an option, because the target is writing the data to s3, and i don't want to write multiple file when data satisfying multiple rule.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, OR conditions between different keys not supported at this moment. As you mentioned, two rules are not an option. The simplest and cheapest approach is unfortunately to create a simple lambda with 10 lines of code to do the filtering for you.

All other solutions (e.g. a step function target for your event rule) is either more complex or more expensive.